# All information about Neural Network

Tags: neural-network

I heard about Neural Network  but there are so many resources and i want to know concrete use of it  and  if possible some small code source with comment. ^^

Answer (score 1):

you might find the following questions to be of use:

[What are some good resources for learning about Artificial Neural Networks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478947/what-are-some-good-resources-for-learning-about-neural-networks)

[Open-source .NET neural network library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549811/open-source-net-neural-network-library)

[Looking for a Good Reference on Neural Networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604078/looking-for-a-good-reference-on-neural-networks)

also you can find two examples of a neural network in this article which also has source code availible:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/aforge_neuro.aspx

if these are not helpful then please make your question more specific

Answer (score 1):

For a rather quick start you could check:

- the [Wikipedia article on Artificial Neural Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_networks) which provides further references
- the [brief introduction to Neural Networks by D. Kriesel](http://www.dkriesel.com/en/science/neural_networks) or maybe
- [Jeff Heaton's website](http://www.jeffheaton.com/ai/) where he also [published parts](http://www.heatonresearch.com/online/introduction-neural-networks-java-edition-2/chapter-1) of his book [Introduction to Neural Networks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1604390085) (with examples in Java resp. C#)

And of course you could search stackoverflow ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

They are used for example to program AI, speach synthesizers, to recognize fingerprints.

And also for many non programming based topics, like checking on airports baggage if it has something dangerous inside, selection of employees :-)

It is so huge topic, and theres no one concrete use.

Answer (score 0):

A good (free!) place to start is the FAQ for Usenet comp.ai.neural-nets:

http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part1/

If you want to code your own, I suggest considering Murray Smith's "Neural Networks for Statistical Modeling".